Stuck in Microsoft One Time Password verification during UI test
I am UI testing (Playwright) a web application that Microsoft Entra protects.
The prompt (below) asks for the password code during the login process, where it very often gets stuck when pressing verify. Also if pressed manually during debugging it doesn't work. There is also no error in the console.
What I tried:

wait a few seconds before clicking
cancel and retry (this is our current solution but is unreliable, often needs many retries, or exceeds our current max. of 10 retries.)

I noticed that this bug happens more frequently when it already occurred in the near past. The error also occurs when only running one test, therefore it seems unlikely that it would be throttled by Microsoft.

